# C# ASP.NET Core alternative to an extension method to register services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, extension-methods, service-locator

I have a problem with my AspNet Core application, I had an extension method to register configurations, on an external library, as in the example:

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddSaml2PIdP(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, SamlSettings settings)
{
           
    foreach (var idP in settings.IdPs)
    {
        builder.AddSaml2p(idP.Scheme, options =>
        {
             options.ServiceProviderOptions = SpOptionsHelper.GetSpOptions(settings);
             ....
        }
    }
    return builder;
}
```

and in Startup class, in ConfigureServices i call this method like this:

```
var samlSettings = _configuration.GetSection(SamlSettings.SamlSection).Get<SamlSettings>();
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddSaml2PIdP(samlSettings);
```

Now unfortunately I had to make some changes, so I need to inject dependencies to be able to perform other operations in that class, so I can no longer use neither a static class nor an extension method, I should do something like this:

```
public class Saml2PExtension
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public Saml2PExtension(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public void AddSaml2PIdP()
    {
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();

        var settings = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SamlSettings>();
        var metadataParser = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISamlMetadataParser>();
        var environment = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
        var builder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationBuilder>();

        foreach (var idP in settings.IdPs)
        {
            builder.AddSaml2p(idP.Scheme, options =>
            {
                options.ServiceProviderOptions = SpOptionsHelper.GetSpOptions(settings);
                ....
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But how should I register this class in the ConfigureServices method and have the configure method called?
Using the new implementation, am I not using the ServiceProvider as the ServiceLocator antipattern?
Alternative solutions are also welcome that could solve the problem in a more elegant way.
Thank you

** EDIT **

In the end, I chose to keep the first core code snippet, added the IWebHostEnvironment parameter to the extension method and instantiated SamlMetadataParser manually, like this:

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddSaml2PIdP(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, IWebHostEnvironment environment, SamlSettings settings)
{
    var metadataParser = new SamlMetadataParser(new ...); // manually create object
    
    foreach (var idP in settings.IdPs)
    {
        builder.AddSaml2p(idP.Scheme, options =>
        {
             options.ServiceProviderOptions = SpOptionsHelper.GetSpOptions(settings);
             
             // Read metadata from file ...
             var idPOptions = metadataParser.Pars(xml);
             ........
        }
    }
    return builder;
}
```

Since I am in the composition root, I think this approach is correct.
Thanks anyway for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by building your own (used-once) container to get your registered services. You can keep your extension method because we have an `IServiceCollection` exposed via the `AuthenticationBuilder`, which is very convenient:

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddSaml2PIdP(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, 
                                                      SamlSettings settings)
{
  using var scope = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope();
  
  //get the services
  var settings = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SamlSettings>();
  var metadataParser = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISamlMetadataParser>();
  var environment = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
  var builder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationBuilder>();
  
  //start using the services

  foreach (var idP in settings.IdPs)
  {
      builder.AddSaml2p(idP.Scheme, options =>
      {
         options.ServiceProviderOptions = SpOptionsHelper.GetSpOptions(settings);
         ....
      }
  }
  return builder; 
}
```

Note that it's possible but then you need to care about the order of registrations of all the dependencies you need for your services you use. Actually you can put the `AddAuthentication` at the end of `ConfigureServices` to ensure that it always succeeds. But if there is anything wrong, an exception will be thrown and we can adjust the order accordingly.

**UPDATE**:

About post-configuration that can be possibly used with `IdpOptions` in IdentityServer4 (for the OP to try it out):

```
services.AddOptions<IdpOptions>()
        .Configure((IdpOptions o, 
                    SamlSettings settings, 
                    ISamlMetadataParser metadataParser,
                    IWebHostEnvironment environment,
                    AuthenticationBuilder builder) => {
              //use your services here to configure next ...
         });
```

Actually the above uses `OptionsBuilder` which supports a way to inject maximum to 5 dependencies. You can use a separate class that implements `IConfigureOptions<IdpOptions>` or `IPostConfigureOptions<IdpOptions>` instead. Then just configure it with `services.ConfigureOptions<TImplementation>()`.

Comment: On the Microsoft documentation it is highly not recommended to use BuildServiceProvider in the ConfigureService method (in this case it is the same thing) for this I would like to look for an alternative solution.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#recommendations

Comment: @pampua84 I know about that, but in this case you have no choice (I'm pretty sure), and here is the line saying that we may still need to use it `Like all sets of recommendations, you may encounter situations where ignoring a recommendation is required` - Personally I don't see clearly why singleton services created in ***separate containers*** can mix with each other. Here I mean the container you build is ***discarded*** completely. If you have any sources talking about that more deeply, I'm happy to take a look into it.

Comment: @pampua84 I'm not familiar with `IdentityServer4`, but looks like you can use ***Automatic Configuration*** (instead of manual configuration as you're using), like guided here https://www.identityserver.com/documentation/saml2p/config-sp/metadata/ - Actually we're not so sure about the ability to post-configure the options used there (like `AuthenticationOptions`, `MvcOptions`, ..) if it supports that, we can use post-configuration and have DI capability to get the services you want for configuration.

Comment: I know there is also automatic configuration, but the problem is that I have to use both manual and automatic configuration and this is where the question arises, thanks anyway

Comment: @pampua84 that's strange, not sure why you want to (or ***must***?) use manual config as well, in this case auto-config (sounds a bit wrong) is actually a more powerful way for you to config it, because all you do is implement an endpoint to help config it with all DI support. It's kind of ***lazy configuration***, but I prefer the post-configuration as supported natively by many options in `asp.net core` framework, like `MvcOptions`, ...

Comment: Can you kindly explain better what you mean by post-configuration? maybe a link with an example?

Comment: @pampua84 see my **UPDATE** section, I'm not so sure if the `IdpOptions` can be configured that way. Actually it should support that, otherwise it's a bit kind of bad design by `IdentityServer4`.

Comment: Ok, tomorrow I will try the second solution, and if everything is ok I will accept the answer. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @pampua84 OK, please let me know the result, otherwise as I said there is almost no way to deal with this except the solution I've provided at first. But if it's not working, I'll consider removing this answer then.

Comment: In the end I chose the solution that I posted in the edit. Thanks anyway for everything.

Comment: @pampua84 so you mean that the solution in my **UPDATE** does not work? :) well so as I said the IdentityServer4 designs it in a bit weird way (because post-configuration is really helpful in scenarios like this). Anyway, your final solution is actually what you have to accept when there is no good solution or even a work-around :)